# Firebase FCM token as security token for Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-security

I am developing an Android app and wondering if using FCM tokens also as authorization tokens (and drop the current custom tokens) would be a good practice.

Example scenario:

1. When application is started for the first time the user gets a new
   FCM token
2. With the login data, the app also sends the token
3. On successful login, the token is stored on the server (with an generated expiration date), and will be sent from now on with each
   request from the client
4. The server uses the token for validation of the request and for sending push notifications
5. When token expiration date is passed, the requests will fail and user will be redirected to login

Everything good so far, but what about FCM token rotation? 
Should I save the FCM token in shared preferences? 
How about user being logged in on multiple devices?

Any advice on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: That means your app's authorization token will never change. So you don't really need such a token :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont be a good practice, if you are using a token to verify client authenticity, as a FCM will be the same for all accounts on that particular device. So in your case, you will be authenticating the device instead of the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the FCM token by calling the

```
(GET) https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/YOUR_APP_TOKEN_HERE
[Header] => 'Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY'
```

Simple and easy.

If token is valid then it will return 200 status code with some more details in JSON format or if it's invalid then status code will be 400 with error detail in JSON format.

Implement this code server side. get token from database and passin the above URL and it will send you token status whether if it expired or not.